# Display category name in Page, Post & Custom Post Type URL

Tags: wordpress

I have added categories in pages, custom post type using register_taxonomy_for_object_type(). 
Now I need help in url rewriting. How can I add category name in page, custom post type and posts urls? The final structure will be something like this:

/categoryname/post_name

/categoryname/page_name

/categoryname/custom_post_type_name

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using category-base.

Go to SETTINGS --> PERMALINKS --> CATEGORY BASE

[image: Wordpress Category Base]